# Ruby on Rails - configuration issue/exception on OSX using Ruby 2.4.4 over rails 5.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

Configuring existing ruby on rails project getting some weird configuration issue - seems like some configuration I'm missing.

I've followed certain steps on my MAC machine as below.

Configure Ruby Environment:
=> rbenv install 2.4.4
=> rbenv local 2.4.4

1. bundle config set path ~/.bundle
2. bundle install
3. npm install
4. bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001

*bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001* casuing serious exception that I'm not able to find the cause.

```
Exiting
/Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/deprecated-2.0.1/lib/deprecated.rb:176:in `instance_method': {:sanitize_conditions=>:sanitize_sql} is not a symbol nor a string (TypeError)
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/deprecated-2.0.1/lib/deprecated.rb:176:in `block in '
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:32:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:5:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:2:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:1:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:256:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:256:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:297:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:275:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:256:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:256:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/workspace/my-project/rails/app/models/cloud/entry.rb:2:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/workspace/my-project/rails/app/models/cloud/entry.rb:1:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `load'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:662:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load_file'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `block in load_interlock'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `load_interlock'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/workspace/my-project/rails/test/factories/cloud/entries.rb:2:in `block in '
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/workspace/my-project/rails/test/factories/cloud/entries.rb:1:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/factory_bot_rails-4.10.0/lib/factory_bot_rails/railtie.rb:21:in `block in '
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `block in execute_hook'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:73:in `block in '
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/workspace/my-project/rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
    from config.ru:3:in `require'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in '
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:in `new'
    from config.ru:in `'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /Users/xxxxxx/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `'
```

Comment: The error message says the problem is on line 2 of `app/models/cloud/entry.rb`. What's there?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `deprecated` gem referenced above is, but if it's [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/deprecated/versions/2.0.1) then note that this version was released in 2009; *long* before ruby 2.4 existed. Maybe this error has happened because you're trying to run the project on a newer ruby version than before?

Comment: starting lines of app/models/cloud/entry.rb are >>>>> module Cloud
  class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base @TomLord

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why it's *started breaking*, but there seems to be a conflict between the (old, no longer hosted on github) `deprecated` gem implementation (which defines a custom `deprecated` method that **expects a symbol** and [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L32) in ActiveRecord v5.1.6.

Comment: I'm guessing you *must* have changed the version of *something*, and in doing so introduced this conflict, but I'm not sure what that change is. My best guess is the version of `ActiveRecord` has been updated, since [that change](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6eaf5c925362f0d1e7bf03a9f82c33569969d9a1) was introduced on an earlier version of rails.

Comment: Try to search who uses gem `deprecated` by keyword `depecated` in your `Gemfile.lock` and remove the gem from `Gemfile`. There should not be gem `deprecated` in rails

Comment: Thanks @itsnikolay the help you provided worked - I tried bundle remove $GEMNAME which was deprecated under lock file and it worked :-) Awesome.

Comment: @shahjapan you're welcome :+1:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove/upgrade gems having **deprecated** keyword in my **Gemfile.lock** by executing command *bundle remove $DEPRECATED_GEMS*.

In my case there were few deprecated gems like, e.g. **dbd_odbc, ruby_odbc**

Originally @itsnikolay has provided this solution towards my problem.